# How can I use pre bootstrapped data to obtain a BCa CI?

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I have bootstrapped two variables (one which is already in the "Impala.csv" file) using a function which resamples and reports the mean for a sample the size of `nrow(data)` for 5000 repetitions. The code is as follows:

```
data<-read.csv("Impala.csv")
allo<-data$distance

data2<-read.csv("2010 - IM.csv")
pro<-data2$pro
n1<-nrow(data2)
boot4000 <- c()
for(i in 1:5000){
s <- sample(data2$xs,n1,replace=T,prob = data2$pro)
boot4000[i] <- mean(s)
}`
```

And then combine the two outputs in a formula, giving me 5000 new variables.

```
d<-(pi/2)*(boot4000*(1/allo))
```

Now I wish to find the BCa confidence intervals for this, but as I understand, the boot function will require me to make a new set of resamples, but I do not want this as the bootstrapping is complete. All I want now is a function which will take my bootstrapped data as is and determine the BCa confidence interval.

http://www.filedropper.com/impala

http://www.filedropper.com/2010-im

Here are the data files I have used

Also, I have tried to create an object imitating a 'boot' object using the following

```
den<-as.matrix(d, ncol=1)
outs<-list(t0=mean(d), t=den, R=5000, L=3)
boot.ci(outs, type="bca")
```

This spits out the error:

> ```
>  Error in if (as.character (boot.out$call[1L]) == "tsboot") warning
>  ("BCa intervals not defined for time series bootstraps") else output
>  <- C (output,: argument is of length zero
> ```

Comment: Have a look at the code for `boot::boot.ci`, or `boot:::bca.ci`. Structure your resamples in an appropriate way that you can run it through these functions.

Comment: Is it correct that you are trying to calculate the c.i. for your vector d , which was produced by your sampling scheme? (ie we dont really need the sampling details / code) If so, can you add an example of d (using `dput(d[1:50])`, and the sample mean of d to your question. If not, can you make the example in your question reproducible please. Also, can you add the code that you used  the produce the error in your comment ^^ to your edit. Thanks

Comment: Ok have updated with links to download the files. Also, yes I wish to calculate the c.i. for the vector 'd'. Thanks

Comment: Could you rollback your edit from 2017 and post the "Update" part of it as a question. If you think it can help others you should make it understandable that it is a solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
outs <- list(t0=mean(d), t=den, R=5000, sim="ordinary", 
             stype="i", weights=rep(0.0002,5000), statistic=meanfun, 
             data=d, call=boot(data=d, statistic = meanfun,R=5000), 
             strata = rep(1,5000), attr="boot", seed=.Random.seed)
```

This is how one can make the object of class boot.out.

Comment: Hi, do you have a link to what each of these arguments mean? The documentation at https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/car/versions/3.0-10/topics/Boot is rather poor.

Comment: @Pronitron it's been a while since I have used car package and am not sure if there's better doc somewhere else. Sorry I couldn't help